# Changes to the .htaccess file are not taken into account

Tags: .htaccess, debian, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7.6 on a Debian 10 + HestiaCP and I tried to update the .htaccess of the site to have a better PageSpeed score.

So, I added my cache rules then uploaded the new file. Nothing happened.

I also tried to reload the Prestashop .htaccess from the dashboard and also restarted the apache2 service.

I precise that this .htaccess is, in a way, working because the shop couldn't work without it. However, the changes I made are not taken into account.

Is there a way to activate these changes?

Comment: There is no "extra" step required to "activate" such changes, also none of the attempts you made. I suggest that you implement a definite syntax error in your file and try again - do you _really_ get an error? Also you need to monitor your http server's error log file, obviously.

Comment: can you post the content of the .htaccess ?

Comment: Please check your *httpd.conf* or *apache.conf* if AllowOverride is not set to *None*. because this usually disables htaccess It should be *AllowOverride All*